# Connect two files with JSON

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

Here I have a two files. One for forms and second php for getting results...

PHP file:

```
$site=$_GET['textfield1']
$xpathfromform=$_GET['textfield2']


$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($site);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = $xpath->query($xpathfromform)->item(0)->textContent;
```

second file is a form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<label>Enter URL address here: 
<input name="textfield" type="text" value="http://www." />
</label>
<label>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
<br />
<br />
Enter xpath location of element:
<input type="text" name="textfield2" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit2" value="Submit" />
<br />
<br />
Selected element is: </label>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

How to connect this two files with JSON... 
example what I need:

1st. type URL and then xpath and click on submit
2nd. when I click I need to start .php file to get result
3th. I must get $result from php file and show in my first file ...

How to connect this two files with json ??? or something else.

Comment: "Connect two files with JSON" makes zero sense. Do you have two JSON files you want to merge?

Comment: please provide examples of what you've tried.  This is not a resource for freeware.  This is to teach.

Comment: the Q is "how to connect this two files" ajax?

Comment: I need to execute php file when I click on submit and return the $result

Comment: @MikiCloud: That has been asked before, please use the search. And search wisely, because these sort of questions are at least asked once per day, so you'll find many duplicates with only limited answers because folks here tend to get boring about these questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, you need to do questions with a bit more sense O.o

So, are you trying to make an AJAX request to your php "file" when the submit button is pressed?

If yes, follow these steps:

1. Add a listener to the submit event for you form `$(form).submit(ajaxSubmit)` when `ajaxSubmit` is a function that will receive an `event` as parameter
2. In `ajaxSubmit` will be some steps:

   - Make sure that the default event (form submit) will not happens `event.preventDefault()`
   - If you need, validate the form fields.
   - Serialize your fields and call `$.ajax` with your parameters and handling a success function
3. The ajax success function, get the result and write it into some element on form page.

So, see an example of [ajax form submit and handling JSON response](http://jsfiddle.net/VsS9Q/3/)